# How do I set PythonHome back to default state?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm currently running on MacOS Catlina.

While trying to install openCV, I've messed up my $PYTHONHOME.

Now, everytime I open up my terminal, it will run continously showing the following text:

```
Current thread 0x0000000112226dc0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

This text will repeat infinitely.

So far, I've tried this typing (alias python /path/to/your/python/home) and it returned that it is not found.

I'm wandered into wrong places on my computer where I'm not capable of understanding the problem.

Please help!

Comment: Environment variables like this are generally set inside a bash script that is run whenever terminal starts. This is usually `~/.bash_profile` on MacOS. Open up that file in a text editor, and remove the line where it is calling python. Alternatively, consider nuking your profile file. Back it up by copying it to another file, and pull things one at a time back into your profile file until it's in the state you "used to" be in. Or just start back from scratch again.

Comment: Okay I see. I ran the `~/.bash_profile` you mentioned and it returned that permission denied. @alkasm How do I go about nuking the profile?

Comment: What do you mean you ran it? I'm suggesting that you edit it, not run it. Just copy it to another location. `cp ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile_old`. Throw a `sudo` to the beginning if you get permission denied. I highly recommend looking up what a bash profile is to get a better understanding of what's going on here. It's not hard at all, just new to you!

Comment: Okay! Appreciate the advice @alkasm, yea thats a good idea. I'll try it after understanding bash profile. :)